# I get the error "Expecting member declaration" when I convert code from Java to Kotlin,why?

Tags: android, kotlin

When I copy java Code A to a Kotlin project in Android Studio 3.01, the  Code A is converted to Code B automatically.

And I add `override` for  `fun override onMenuItemClick(item: MenuItem)` in  Code B by the hint of Android Studio 3.01.

But I get still the error "Expecting member declaration" in Code B, what wrong with my kotlin Code B?

**Code  A**

```
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;

 public static  void showPopup(View v, final Context mContext) {

        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, v);
        popup.inflate(R.menu.menu_more);

        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                return HandleMenu(item, mContext);
            }
        });
        popup.show();
 }
```

**Code  B**

```
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;

    fun showPopup(v: View, mContext: Context) {

        val popup = PopupMenu(mContext, v)
        popup.inflate(R.menu.menu_more)

        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(object : PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            fun override onMenuItemClick(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
                return HandleMenu(item, mContext)
            }
        })

        popup.show()

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply replace this:

```
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(object : PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            fun override onMenuItemClick(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
                return HandleMenu(item, mContext)
            }
        })
```

with this:

```
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener { item -> HandleMenu(item, mContext) }
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be `override fun` instead of `fun override`.

Also you can make use of Kotlin SAM and simplify it to `popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener { item -> HandleMenu(item, mContext) }` as the IDE suggests.